# I need to use the .post and .get Ajax functions to get some php to display in some div tags in an index file

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have been given a task which as follows:

TASK STEPS

1. Create two DIVs with unique ID tags
   a. These will be used to display the data returned from the AJAX
2. Create two A tags
   a. The HREF can be left blank
   b. Add a REL attribute to each
   c. Set the REL of one of the A tags to get and the other to post
3. Write a single jQuery click action to capture all clicks on all A tags
   a. Remember to disable the default click action of the A tag
   b. This click event must implement an AJAX action
4. The method of the AJAX (GET or POST) will be defined by using the REL               attribute of the A
5. The data returned from the PHP to the AJAX will be displayed in one of the    two DIVs, based upon the
   AJAX method that was used; one for GET and one for POST

This is what I have done so far -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Skills Tasks</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>

<a href="" rel="get">get</a>
<a href="" rel="post">post</a>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get("data.php"); 




     });
 });

 </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

This is what's in the PHP file -

```
   <?php
   echo 'The data was returned';
   exit;
    ?>
```

Comment: What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Sounds like homework or something similar :)

Comment: You're not doing anything with the data once you get it.

Comment: So should it be $('#one').get("data.php"); so the php from the file displays in the div?

Comment: to do it like that it would be $('#one').load("data.php") but its the wrong function

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).attr('rel')=='get'){
            $.get("data.php",function(data){$('#one').text(data);}); 
        }
        if($(this).attr('rel')=='post'){
            $.post("data.php",function(data){$('#two').text(data);}); 
        }


    });
});
```